# Array of custom Java objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to create an array of Person (a class that with variables String name, and double total).  But for some reason, creating a second Person replaces(?) the first person. . .

```
Person[] p = new Person[40];
    
p[0] = new Person("Jango", 32);
p[1] = new Person("Grace", 455);
    
System.out.println( p[0].getName() );
System.out.println( p[1].getName() );
System.out.println( p[0].equals(p[1]) );
```

The output is:

```
Grace
Grace
false
```

Why isn't it:

```
Jango
Grace
false
```

????????????

```
public class Person {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Person next;
    private String name;
    private double total;

    public Person(String _name)
    {
        name = _name;
        total = 0.0;
        next = null;
    }

    public Person(String _name, double _total)
    {
        name = _name;
        total = _total;
        next = null;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the person class? maybe you use a static variable to store the name?

Comment: Can we see the Person class?

Comment: Can you show us the constructor of Person?

Comment: Assuming a sane definition of `Person`, this shouldn't happen. Either you typo'd one of the array indices in your actual code, or the error is in `Person`.

Comment: Plus a lack of implementation of equals/hashCode for the last line of code (which would justify a false).

Comment: You need to look up what "static" means in a class field, and also how object comparison works in Java.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Removed all static keywords from `Person` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the `name` instance variable is declared as static, making it a class variable.  Any change to name will be changed for every instance of that class.. You need to remove the static identifier from  `name` and from `total` and your code will work fine.

Comment: If they are static they are not instance variables. So your statement is contradictory.

Comment: Well, name would be an instance variable for a Person class.. and that is what he is trying to do.. That is why I used the term.

Comment: If they are static they are class variables, not instance variables. Arent't they?

Comment: You are correct... And I am aware. I was trying to say that he declared instance variables as static... making them class variables. which is not what he intended to do. Sorry for not typing it all out..

Answer (score 3):

Currently these variables are `static` which means that they  they will retain the last values assigned.

```
private static String name;
private static double total;
```

You need to make these fields class *instance* variables:

```
private String name;
private double total;
```

See [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your fields are static. They should not be, if you want them to be able to store a separate instance of a name and total for each instance of the class.